# skip frame rendering if falling behind

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, rtsp

I have the code below that uses ffmpeg libraries (v3.1.4 with the Autogen wrapper) to render RTSP video in my application. The code works very well generally. However, the `receptical.Write` method is not particularly performant. On slow machines my video rendering starts to fall behind. Eventually my buffers fill up and I start to see video corruption. How can I change the code below to skip frames when it starts to fall behind? If there are multiple frames ready, I really only care to show the frame most recently available -- this is live video after all. I believe that the `avcodec_send_packet` and `avcodec_receive_frame` methods are approximately 1-to-1.

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    if (ffmpeg.av_read_frame(pFormatContext, pPacket) != 0)
    {
        // end of the stream
        ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
        break;
    }

    if (pPacket->stream_index != pStream->index || (pPacket->flags & ffmpeg.AV_PKT_FLAG_CORRUPT) > 0)
    {
        // this should never happen; we only subscribe to one stream
        // and I believe corrupt packets are automatically discarded
        ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
        continue;
    }

    var sendResult = ffmpeg.avcodec_send_packet(pCodecContext, pPacket);
    if (sendResult < 0)
    {
        // one of the possible results is a "buffer full", but I don't think that should happen as long as we call 1-to-1 receive_frame
        ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
        _logger.Warn("Failure in FFmpeg avcodec_send_packet: " + sendResult);
        break;
    }

    while (ffmpeg.avcodec_receive_frame(pCodecContext, pDecodedFrame) == 0)
    {
        var src = &pDecodedFrame->data0;
        var dst = &pConvertedFrame->data0;
        var srcStride = pDecodedFrame->linesize;
        var dstStride = pConvertedFrame->linesize;
        ffmpeg.sws_scale(pConvertContext, src, srcStride, 0, height, dst, dstStride);

        sbyte* convertedFrameAddress = pConvertedFrame->data0;

        int linesize = dstStride[0];

        if (receptical == null)
        {
            receptical = writableBitampCreationCallback.Invoke(new DetectedImageDimensions {Width = width, Height = height, Format = DetectedPixelFormat.Bgr24, Linesize = linesize});
        }

        var imageBufferPtr = new IntPtr(convertedFrameAddress);
        receptical.Write(width, height, imageBufferPtr, linesize);

        ffmpeg.av_frame_unref(pDecodedFrame);
    }
    ffmpeg.av_packet_unref(pPacket);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Depending on how you are syncing your playback, whether it be against the system clock or otherwise. You can check the PTS of the incoming packets and if they are starting to lag behind playback then dump them. Realtime decoding on the fly is cpu intensive.
2. The decoding and using sws_scale will eat your cpu up. I don't know what 'writableBitampCreationCallback' is but I'm also guessing that is eating up cpu time too. The best way around this is to separate your decoding into separate threads, one each for audio and video and maybe subtitles. This at least will free up cpu time. The packets can be sent to each thread.
3. You are not showing how the video is finally rendered. Using something like openGL you can render the decoded frame (YUV420) direct using a YUV to RGB shader which cuts out the need to convert the frame to RGB. This saves a hell of a lot of cpu time.

Below is an example of a fragment shader which takes the 3 textures from the YUV data. Hopefully this will help you along shaving a lot of cpu time.

```
precision mediump float;
uniform sampler2D qt_TextureY;
uniform sampler2D qt_TextureU;
uniform sampler2D qt_TextureV;
varying vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
void main(void)
{
    float y = texture2D(qt_TextureY, qt_TexCoord0).r;
    float u = texture2D(qt_TextureU, qt_TexCoord0).r - 0.5;
    float v = texture2D(qt_TextureV, qt_TexCoord0).r - 0.5;
    gl_FragColor = vec4( y + 1.403 * v,
                         y - 0.344 * u - 0.714 * v,
                         y + 1.770 * u, 1.0); \
}
```

Comment: Do you think I can use the PTS to know that I'm more than one frame behind? I'm not familiar with it.

Comment: I'm actually just implementing it now because I'm having to de-interlace 50i frames too. I'm syncing to the system clock so when the packet reader reaches packets that are out by 2/50th's of a second, I won't add them to the decoder. So far so good. So yeah it can be done. I'm only needing to do that so the player will work on old ARM hardware. Use av_q2d() to convert the PTS value to a double.

Comment: I ended up having to use a separate thread for the `av_read_frame` calls (since it's a blocking call when no data is available). With that in place I clear my packet queue whenever I get a new key frame. That seems to be working quite well for me now.